# confused while querying junction object

Tags: batch, query, relationships, childrelationship

I am working on a batch and am writing a query but am getting confused because of the relationship... The batch is written on a junction object, Account_BOB__c, between 2 parents Account & Book_Of_Business__c. When an Account_BOB__c is created, a field on Account is updated, based upon the fields on Book_Of_Business. I'm currently working through the logic of execute method but I have confused myself. Here is my code thus far:

```
global class Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Schedulable {
global String query = 'SELECT Id, Account__c, Book_of_Business__c, Status__c, Book_of_Business__r.Level__c, Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c FROM Account_BOB__c ' +
   'WHERE Status__c = Active' +
   'AND Effective_Date__c = TODAY';

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account_BOB__c> scope) { 
    Set<Id> accBOBIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Account> accByAccBOBIdMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    
     for(Account_BOB__c accBOB : scope) { 
         accBOBIdSet.add(accBOB.Id);
    }
    
    for(Book_of_Business__c bob : [SELECT Id FROM Book_of_Business__c WHERE Account_BOB__c IN :accBOBIdSet])
```

The error is coming on the last line. Because there is no Account_BOB__c on Book_Of_Business__c.

I am trying to get the Book_Of_Business fields associated with each Account BOB in my scope. But not sure how to do that in my `WHERE` because this object being on the child side of the relationship.

I'm sorry if I explained this incorrectly, but does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are over complicating the steps involved.

This example of the `execute` method iterates over the items in `scope` and builds `Account` records to be updated using data found on the related (and queried for) `Book_of_Business__c` records.

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account_BOB__c> scope) {
    
    // these are the accounts which we're going to populate data on
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();
            
    for (Account_BOB__c accBOB : scope) {
        // assuming you have queried for the data
        // so that it exists on the accBOB record in
        // this for loop

        // sobject for the account record which will be updated            
        Account acct;

        // check to see if this account has already been added to the map in this scope
        if (accountsToUpdate.containsKey(accBOB.Account__c)) {
            // get the sobject from the map 
            acct = accountsToUpdate.get(accBOB.Account__c);
        } else {
            // create a new one
            acct = new Account(Id = accBOB.Account__c);
        }
        
        // populate your fields with concrete references
        // acct.your_field_name__c = accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c;
        
        // or dynamic references by string API name
        // acct.put('your_field_name__c') = accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c;

        // put the account record into the map for updating
        accountsToUpdate.put(acct.Id, acct);
    }

    update accountsToUpdate.values(); // get the list of Account from the map and update
}
```

Comment: thanks! i always get stuck in my head and overcomplicate things, i really appreciate you helping me see it this way.